# Opening a url in a non-default browser in a cocoa app

Tags: cocoa, browser

How can a cocoa application open a url in a browser other than the default browser? NSWorkspace doesn’t appear to offer any method for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSWorkspace has a couple of methods:

- [openFile:withApplication:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-openFile_withApplication_)
- [openURLs:withAppBundleIdentifier:options:additionalEventParamDescriptor:launchIdentifiers:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-BCIJJBCG)

To use the second method, you'll need to know the bundle identifier of the browser you want to open.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I read the beginning of that method and assumed it would work because of the description, "Opens one or more files from an array of URLs.”

Much thanks!